# Do I need google API key to download some names from freebase?

Tags: python

I want to collect some names like: location names, organization names, etc. from freebase. I do some research and find some python scripts. But it looks like I need to register a google API key something ? Is it the must and if yes do you know how could I get that?
Is there any example that they do similar thing ? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can download the entire freebase
2. you need a key to use the api. the documentation for the api of free base can found in:
   https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/getting-started#api-keys
   and
3. to obtain a key: https://code.google.com/apis/console/